# boolean loopd keys strings comparator

Tags: python, string, loops, frequency

i am doing a python project and i wanna compare a string to a list of keys and values - if all the keys were to match up a certain number of times with a word string, it should return True for example -
def `compareTo(word, hand):`

```
   kal = False 
   for d in wordlists: 
       if d in word: 
          kal = True 
   return kal
```

it always returns false how can i make it return true?!? please help!!!

so if

```
word = "hammer"
```

and

```
hand =  {'a': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 2, 'e': 1}
```

values represent the frequency of each letter
if I insert parameters which are true, how can I make it return true and not false...

```
comapreTo("hammer",{'a': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 2, 'e': 1})
```

should return True and not False and `comapreTo("hammers",{'a': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 1})` should return false and not true!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Counter` to count letter frequencies:

```
from collections import Counter

def compareTo(word, hand):
    return Counter(word) == hand
```

For example, `Counter("hammer")` is `Counter({'m': 2, 'a': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 1})`; since `Counter` is dictionary-like, this will compare equal to `{'a': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 2, 'e': 1}`.

`Counter` is built in to Python 2.7 and Python 3.x. If you need to use it in Python 2.6 or earlier, you can get it from here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/.

Comment: Nice. I would add info that Counter is in Python since 2.7. In some cases this might be a deal breaker ...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def compareTo(word, hand):
    d = hand.copy()
    for c in word:
        d[c] = d.get(c, 0) - 1
        if d[c] < 0:
            return False
    return True

word = "hammer"
hand =  {'a': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'm': 2, 'e': 1}

print compareTo(word, hand)  # => True    
print compareTo("hammers", hand)  # => False
print compareTo("plum", {'f': 1, 'h': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1, 'y': 1})  # => True
```

Comment: how come it doesn't work for this case - >>> plum = "plum"
>>> pluma = {'f': 1, 'h': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1, 'y': 1}
>>> print compareTo(plum, pluma)
False

Comment: in what case it doesn't work? I'm getting outputs that are in comments ... If you want to make it work if _hand_ is superset of minimum matching one than last `return` should be just `return True`

Comment: @user2152315 to make it work for your case you need to apply change from comment above

Comment: in the case "plum" and {'f': 1, 'h': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1, 'y': 1} it returns False when it should return True

Comment: @user2152315 I would recommend changing problem description to strengthen that numbers in those _hand_ dict are lower bounds - not equal values

Comment: so how would i  make them lower bounds, kkonrad?

Comment: it doesn't work in the sense that some of the values are wrong and not correct...

Comment: some of the comments return False when they should be returning True...do ya get what i'm saying?

Comment: Only one example is returning False which comes from your problem definition which which you described as it should return False ...